# SharePoint 2010 file upload via REST api

Tags: 2010, rest, api

I am developing application that access files on SharePoint 2010 via REST API

I referenced this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx), so I made it download and get metadata for documents.

But, While I am trying upload file, I can't specify endpoint uri.

I tried as `"http:// server/sites/document/"` but failed with

> 'cannot retry due to redirection, in streaming mode' error.

And with `"http:// server/sites/document/filetobeuploaded"`,

> HTTP 404 error

What I tried method is POST.

My development environment is java, SharePoint 2010 and REST API(jersey api).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Copy Web Service method** to upload document in **SharePoint 2010** But it is not a method of REST API.

Below is the article from where you will get all the details.

[Uploading Content Into SharePoint (Let me count the ways)](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2009/09/uploading-content-into-sharepoint-let.html)

Below is the code **WORKING in SharePoint 2013** to upload a file in the same domain by using the `REST API` and `jQuery`

> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function () {
>
>     // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
>     if (!window.FileReader) {
>         alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
>     }
> });
>
> // Upload the file.
> // You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
> function uploadFile() {
>
>     // Define the folder path for this example.
>     var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';
>
>     // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
>     var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
>     var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
>
>     // Get the server URL.
>     var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
>
>     // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
>     // Get the local file as an array buffer.
>     var getFile = getFileBuffer();
>     getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
>
>         // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
>         var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
>         addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
>
>             // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
>             var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
>             getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {
>
>                 // Change the display name and title of the list item.
>                 var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
>                 changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
>                     alert('file uploaded and updated');
>                 });
>                 changeItem.fail(onError);
>             });
>             getItem.fail(onError);
>         });
>         addFile.fail(onError);
>     });
>     getFile.fail(onError);
>
>     // Get the local file as an array buffer.
>     function getFileBuffer() {
>         var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
>         var reader = new FileReader();
>         reader.onloadend = function (e) {
>             deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
>         }
>         reader.onerror = function (e) {
>             deferred.reject(e.target.error);
>         }
>         reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
>         return deferred.promise();
>     }
>
>     // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
>     function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {
>
>         // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
>         var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
>         var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
>
>         // Construct the endpoint.
>         var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
>                 "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
>                 "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
>                 serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
>
>         // Send the request and return the response.
>         // This call returns the SharePoint file.
>         return jQuery.ajax({
>             url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
>             type: "POST",
>             data: arrayBuffer,
>             processData: false,
>             headers: {
>                 "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>                 "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
>                 "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
>     function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {
>
>         // Send the request and return the response.
>         return jQuery.ajax({
>             url: fileListItemUri,
>             type: "GET",
>             headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
>         });
>     }
>
>     // Change the display name and title of the list item.
>     function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {
>
>         // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
>         // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
>         // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
>         // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
>         var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
>             itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);
>
>         // Send the request and return the promise.
>         // This call does not return response content from the server.
>         return jQuery.ajax({
>             url: itemMetadata.uri,
>             type: "POST",
>             data: body,
>             headers: {
>                 "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
>                 "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>                 "content-length": body.length,
>                 "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
>                 "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
>             }
>         });
>     }
> }
>
> // Display error messages. 
> function onError(error) {
>     alert(error.responseText);
> }
> ```

Check this article for more details.

[Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx)

Comment: Did you test it in SharePoint 2010? It seems it will only work in 2013.

Comment: Also give the reference if you have copied the code from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-upload-file-in-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-r/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but i get it from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx

Comment: okay. Now provide the reference in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my target version is 2010.

Comment: I provided the link in my answer to achieve the same in SharePoint 2010.